# WiX MSMQ: The Product element contains an unexpected child element 'msmq:MessageQueue'

Tags: xml, windows, wix, installation, windows-installer

I am using the WiX MSMQ extension to create queues with the following code:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:msmq="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/MsmqExtension">

<Product Id="*" Name="Blah" Language="1033" Version="2.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Blah Inc." UpgradeCode="{7FB782AF-178B-4705-893A-CE9B54EF54C0}">
<Package Id ="*" Keywords="Installer" Description="Blah Installer" Manufacturer="Blah Inc." InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="yes" />   

<Property Id="HASMSMQ"> 
  <RegistrySearch Id="MSMQIsInstalled" Root="HKLM" Key="System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSMQ" Name="ImagePath" Type="raw" /> 
</Property> 

<Condition Message="You must run the installer as administrator to install this product.">Privileged</Condition>
<Condition Message="The MSMQ service must be installed to install this product."><![CDATA[INSTALLED OR HASMSMQ]]></Condition>

<msmq:MessageQueue Id="Blah1" Label="Blah 1" Transactional="no" PrivLevel="none" PathName=".\Private$\Blah1" />
<msmq:MessageQueue Id="Blah2" Label="Blah 2" Transactional="no" PrivLevel="none" PathName=".\Private$\Blah2" />
```

However, when I execute candle.exe -ext WixMsmqExtension Blah.wxs I get an error: "CNDL0005: The Product element contains an unexpected child element 'msmq:MessageQueue'"

I don't understand why, I have the reference and namespace. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msmq:MessageQueue` must be a child of the `Component` element. You message queue will be "installed" together with the parent component. The condition of the component will also serve as a condition for the message queue creation.

See the [doc reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/msmq/messagequeue.html) for more details.